# Смена данных в json в foreach

Tags: php, json

Я пытаюсь сделать так чтобы в json менялось значение

```
<form method="POST">
    <?php
    $json2323232 = file_get_contents('avatar/'.$_COOKIE['accname'].'.json');
    $data2323232 = json_decode($json2323232, true);
    $json232323245 = file_get_contents('accounts/'.$_COOKIE['accname'].'.json');
    $data232323245 = json_decode($json232323245, true);
    

foreach($data2323232 as $element1){
    if(isset($_POST[$element1])){
    $data232323245['Avatar'] = $element1;

    $newJsonString = json_encode($data232323245);
    file_put_contents('accounts/'.$_COOKIE['accname'].'.json', $newJsonString);
    
    }
    echo '<input value="'.$element1.'" style="background-image:url(http://test.parodyiu.beget.tech/'.$element1.');" type="submit" name="'.$element1.'"><br>';
}
    ?>
    </form>
```

Но ничего не происходит, не могу понять почему

Comment: Не по теме вопроса, но хорошенько подумайте, что будет если пользователь запишет в куку accname что-то вроде `../../`

Comment: вам сперва нужно научиться отлаживать код. Самый лучший способ - научиться пользоваться X-DEBUG , если таких возможностей нет - то для начала распечатайте print_r($data2323232) - может там данных нет, затем выведите на печать любой символ если if сработал, а то может быть что if ни разу не выполняется, а потом поймете в чем проблема, может у вас $element1 - это не строка. И включите error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: там присутствует тот элемент который нужен +результат выводит но менять именно не хочет